# Hive lock in transactional table used in joins

Tags: join, hive, transactions, azure-hdinsight

We are facing this strange issue with Hive on HDInsight 4.0 - Hive  3.1.0
By default, Hive is set to handle all tables as transactional.
We have 3 tables which join together:

- a
- b
- c

In initial phase 2 of those tables were partitioned by year/month  (b,c).
Now, we have repartitioned them by year/month/day (b,c).
Which generates a number of around 200 partitions for each table(b,c).

Now if we do a select from a join b join c we get a transaction lock error.
However, if I do Select a join b - works fine, if I do Select a join c works fine.

Also, if I restrict in the join clause for one of the newly partitioned tables to scan only one partition like

`Select a join b on 1=1 join c on 1=1 and c.YEAR=2019 AND c.MONTH=1`

it also works fine.

It seems that the increased number of partitions which the join has to scan, or something like that is preventing Hive to take a read lock on those tables... which is very strange, since the tables do not share anything, except the same database.

Any ideas?

Full error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Error in acquiring locks: Error communicating with the metastore
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.waitForOperationToComplete(HiveStatement.java:401)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:266)
at com.hortonworks.hivestudio.hive.HiveJdbcConnectionDelegate.execute(HiveJdbcConnectionDelegate.java:56)
at com.hortonworks.hivestudio.hive.actor.StatementExecutor.runStatement(StatementExecutor.java:93)
at com.hortonworks.hivestudio.hive.actor.StatementExecutor.handleMessage(StatementExecutor.java:74)
at com.hortonworks.hivestudio.hive.actor.HiveActor.onReceive(HiveActor.java:45)
at akka.actor.UntypedAbstractActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(AbstractActor.scala:243)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:514)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:512)
at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:132)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Can you check if you have either of `hive.limit.query.max.table.partition` or `hive.metastore.limit.partition.request` set in Hive Metastore config?

Comment: Nothing like that in Ambari settings or in hive-site.xml